# Limit of $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=0$

Tags: limits

How to best show that 
$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}=0.$$

I've tried to make a fraction out of it, but then I get 0/0, and so I take the derivative using L'Hopitals, and it just gets messier and messier.

Would just like a hint.

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\sin x-x\cos x}{x\sin x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{(\sin x-x\cos x)'}{(x\sin x)'}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\cos x-(\cos x-x\sin x)}{\sin x+x \cos x}\\&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\sin x}{(\sin x/x)+\cos x}\\&=\frac{0}{1+1}\\&=0.\end{align}$$
Here, note that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1.$

Comment: This made sense. Thanks.

Comment: @dan: You are welcome. sorry maybe I wrote too much.

Comment: One more thing: if x was instead approaching pi from the left-handed side, would the limit = infinity, as 1/Pi is a positive number, and cos(x) / sin(x) approaches negative infinity, and as I was subtracting them, it becomes Positive number - (-infinity) = infinity?

Comment: @dan: Yes, you are right.

Comment: It gets simpler if you change $x\sin x$ in the denominator into $x^2$ before applying L'Hôpital's theorem (which can surely be done as at the end we *do* find a limit).

Answer (score 2):

Use the Taylor expansions
$$\sin x = x-\frac 16 x^3+O(x^5),\qquad \cos x = 1-\frac 12x^2+O(x^4), $$
to find that the expression is $\frac13 x+O(x^3)$.

Comment: Isn't there another way? I'm not supposed to solve with Taylor expansions, just regular manipulation, I think.

Answer (score 1):

This question deserves the following joke:

### Note: Both these answers are intentionally wrong.

---

**Physics student**:
Let's use the fact that $\sin x \approx x $ for sufficiently small values of $x$.
$$\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x} \approx \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0+} \underbrace{\frac{0 - (-\sin x)}{1}}_{\text{Using L'Hosp.}}  = \sin 0 = 0$$

---

**Math student:**
Let us use the facts that

- $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$,
- $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$
- $1 = \frac{x}{x},\space x\neq0$
  $$
  \require{cancel}
  \begin{align}
  \text{LHS} &= \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot x}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1 - \cos x}{x} \\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{1 - \cos^2 x}{x\cdot (1+ \cos x)}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to 0+} \frac{\left(\frac{\sin x}{x}\right)^2 \cdot x^\cancel{2}}{\cancel{x}\cdot (1+ \cos x)}\\
  &= \lim_{x\to0+} \frac{x}{1+\cos x}\\
  &= \frac{0}{1 + \cos 0} = \frac{0}{1+1} = \frac{0}{2} = 0 = \text{RHS} \tag {Q.E.D.}
  \end{align}
  $$

---

Comment: I would very much like an explanation on why both answers are wrong. But answers seem correct to me (though I don't claim to be an expert on the matter).

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
I&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac 1x-\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}\\
I&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac1{2x}-\frac{\cos 2x}{\sin 2x}\\
2I&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac1{x}-\frac{2\cos 2x}{\sin 2x}\\
2I-I&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\frac{\cos x}{\sin x}-\frac{2\cos 2x}{\sin 2x}\\
I&=\lim_{x\to 0+}\left(\tan x\right)=0
\end{align}$$
Using the famous result: $$\large \cot x-\tan x=2\frac{1-\tan^2x}{2\tan x}=2\cot 2x$$

Comment: How do you prove the limit exists?

Comment: @egreg what do you mean?

Comment: You can't do arithmetic with $I$ until you have proved it means a real number. What you have proved is that *if* the limit exists, it is $0$; which is not a proof the limit is $0$.

Comment: @egreg I don't know how to prove that, your point is correct, can you help me?

Comment: I already helped not downvoting.

Answer (score -2):

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x}-\frac{\cos (x)}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{\sin (x)}-\frac{\cos (x)}{\sin(x)}=\frac{1-\cos (x)}{\sin(x)}=\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\ \sin(x)}{\cos(x)}=\frac{0}{1}=0$$

Here we used L'Hopital (after the third $=$ sign) and we used the identity $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{ x}{\sin (x)}=1$